# Set role expiry programmatically in uc_roles_expirations table?

Tags: 7

I am moving a site to drupal. In that site role expire was manually set by admin.

In my drupal site I want this with the use of ubercart recurring subscription.

So how can I set a role expiration date programmatically which will work as we assign a role in features of any product purchase?

Comment: Why not do it with the Rules module which amongst many things allows you to assign or unassign roles for a wide range of system events including 'content of type X has just been saved'?

Comment: and how to combine it with ubercart role features?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved Just by Database entry :

```
$expiredate = date('U', strtotime($expiry));
    db_insert('uc_roles_expirations')
    ->fields(array(
      'uid' => $uid,
      'rid' => 6,
      'expiration' => $expiredate,
    ))
    ->execute();
```

Comment: How does this solve this problem?

Comment: I added the role expiry in `uc_role_expirations` table using my custom script. So the role expiry will work based on the ubercart standard.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this with Rules is as follows. I've not done this with Ubercart per se but it should work.

- in Rules, create a component that will perform an action (i.e. remove a role)

  - a component of type 'action set' with a single 'node' variable
  - action: create a list of nodes (products or users?)
  - add a loop
  - add an action to this loop that will remove role
  - *** more actions may be required here depending on your setup ***
  - save the component
- now create a rule that will react 'after saving new content
- condition: you need to check for proper content type (Rules requires this)
- action: schedule component evaluation (select the component created above)

  - set date/time (the node published date; any date field will also work)
  - set offset  (e.g. + 4 weeks, + 52 weeks, etc.)
  - save
- when a new (product) node is created, an action item will be added to the Schedule of items to be evaluated on cron.

Checkout Nodeone's screencast [Using fields for setting evaluation time](http://nodeone.se/en/using-fields-for-setting-evaluation-time) for more information.

Cheers!

Comment: I thought this to be done with taking a field in user profile and set the expire date in that field and remove the role on the basis of the value saved in user profile.

Comment: That should also work.

Comment: yup i will try both tommorow... that will be perfect for my need. ;)

Comment: Great. Let me know how it goes... :-)

Comment: check my answer.... ;)